# Select only nodes which contain a specific child node and format them into YAML

Tags: xslt, yaml

This has been doing my head for a whole day. Can you help me out?!
I have a simple xml file. using xslt i'd like to convert it into yaml file. problems are:

1. i need to organize the output in a way i should only catch **specyfic values**  from xml tags and put them to specyfic yaml dictionaries *(work, address)*
2. some xml tags will have names() or attrs()  i **can't predict** in advance - hence i cannot just grab them by names() or position() or some other logic. I can make some assumptions but not for all tags...
3. While formatting the output I find it really hard to set dictionary key (*work, address*) for for yaml file after i've selected values i want - i can either set key for all children of ofert (which i don't require) or i can set key for each individual element which is not what i want.

consider this:

```
<data>
   <info>some info</info>
   <data>some data</data>
   <list>
         <ofert>
            <unknow>....</unknow>
            <unknow1>....</unknow1>
            <id>00934</id>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <street>Euston rd.</street>
            <postcode>SE23GH</postcode>
            <job>IT</job>
            <position>boss</position>
            <unknow>....</unknow>
            <unknow4>....</unknow4>
            <unknow2>....</unknow2>
            <unknow3>....</unknow3>
         </ofert>
   </list>
</data>
```

I would like output like:

```
data:
    info: ....
    data: ....
        list:
            ofert:
                id: 00934
                name: Bob
                address: {street: Euston rd, postcode: SE23GH }
                work: {job: IT, position: boss }
                other: {unknow: ....., unknow1: .... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple XSLT 1.0 solution that does not include the 'other:' yaml element ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*" />

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:call-template name="indent">
   <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( local-name(), ': ', text(), '&#x0A;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ofert">
  <xsl:variable name="indent" select="count(ancestor::*)" />
  <xsl:call-template name="indent">
   <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$indent"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( local-name(), ': ', text(), '&#x0A;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="id" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
  <xsl:call-template name="indent">
   <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$indent + 1"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
    'address: {street: ', street/text(),
    ', postcode: ', postcode,' }&#x0A;')"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="indent">
   <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$indent + 1"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
     'work: {job: ', job,
  ', position: ', position, ' }&#x0A;')"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="indent">
  <xsl:param name="spaces" />
  <xsl:if test="$spaces > 0">
   <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="indent">
    <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$spaces - 1"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An XSLT 2.0 solution would be a lot simpler. Let us know if you are not constrained to XSLT 1.0.

If I get some time, I will update the solution to include the 'other:' element. Basically, the technique will simply be to define a named template to produce the associate arrays like address: , work: and other:, where the input parameters include indent level, label ('address' etc.), and list of associative array member nodes. I hope you get the idea.

---

## UPDATE

Here is the XSLT 2.0 version, which includes the 'other' yaml element ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:zzart="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192960">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="indent-unit" select = "'  '" />

<xsl:function name="zzart:indent" as="xs:string">
 <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="fn:string-join( for $in in 1 to $level return $indent-unit, '')" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@*" />

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( zzart:indent( count(ancestor::*)), local-name(), ': ', text(), '&#x0A;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ofert">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor::*)" />
  <xsl:variable name="indent" select="zzart:indent( $level)" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( $indent, local-name(), ': ', text(), '&#x0A;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="id" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
  <xsl:call-template name="associative-array">
   <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
   <xsl:with-param name="array-name" select="'address'" />
   <xsl:with-param name="array-members" select="(street, postcode)" />
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:call-template name="associative-array">
   <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
   <xsl:with-param name="array-name" select="'work'" />
   <xsl:with-param name="array-members" select="(job, position)" />
  </xsl:call-template>

  <xsl:call-template name="associative-array">
   <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
   <xsl:with-param name="array-name" select="'other'" />
   <xsl:with-param name="array-members" select="*[not(self::id)][not(self::name)]
                                                 [not(self::street)][not(self::postcode)]
                                                 [not(self::job)][not(self::position)]" />
  </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="associative-array">
 <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer" />
 <xsl:param name="array-name" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:param name="array-members"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( zzart:indent( $level), $array-name, ': {')" />
 <xsl:for-each select="$array-members">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( local-name(), ': ', text(), if (position() != last()) then ', ' else ' }&#x0A;')" />
 </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant!!! I've only started to learn XSLT a couple days ago so it's still feels like dark magic to me. The way you have solved it using associate arrays and sorted out spacing in yaml file with params and separate template is incredible :! If it's not too time consuming i'd love to see the XSLT 2.0 ver. as im not constrained to 1.0 . Still don't get how you can concatinate two or more values at the same time - when i look at this code i can't help this for each loop going on in my head ...

Comment: You can concatinate with the concat() function.

Comment: Thanks for your input - it's spot on. As i'm going to have lots of xml to format to Yaml i'm going to use this to great extend! All best.